# How to add image during programmatic product import in prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I can't find a proper documentation on adding images during product inserting. Here is the working code of my xml product import script. I have no idea how to add product images also while adding a product.

```
foreach ($xml->Products as $product_xml)
{
    if ($product_xml->Valid_internet_product == 1)
    {
        /* Update an existing product or Create a new one */
        $id_product = (int)Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT id_product FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product WHERE reference = \''.pSQL($product_xml->Reference).'\'');
        $product = $id_product ? new Product((int)$id_product, true) : new Product();
        $product->reference = $product_xml->Reference;
        $product->price = (float)$product_xml->Price;
        $product->active = (int)$product_xml->Active_product;
        $product->weight = (float)$product_xml->Weight;
        $product->minimal_quantity = (int)$product_xml->MinOrderQty;
        $product->id_category_default = 2;
        $product->name = utf8_encode($product_xml->Products_name);
        $product->description = utf8_encode($product_xml->Description);
        $product->description_short = utf8_encode($product_xml->Short_Description);
        $product->link_rewrite = Tools::link_rewrite($product_xml->Products_name);
        $product->image_url = 'http://i.imgur.com/jLThaBj.jpg';
        if (!isset($product->date_add) || empty($product->date_add))
            $product->date_add = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $product->date_upd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $id_product ? $product->updateCategories(array(2)) : $product->addToCategories(array(2));


        $product->save();

        echo 'Product <b>'.$product->name.'</b> '.($id_product ? 'updated' : 'created').'<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is implemented with the following method:

```
AdminImportControllerCore::copyImg()
```

You can just copy/paste it, or change it if you need.

Comment: What are the parameters.?
edit : I am getting this error :Fatal error: Call to protected method AdminImportControllerCore::copyImg() from context

Comment: PrestaShop is open source solution, which means that you can open the file and see the parameters. As I said you need to copy that method and make it part of your class or as a function. Still your code above will need a lot more work and knowledge in PrestaShop in order to work smoothly.

Comment: Thanks got it. Sorted out. I extended that class my own.

Answer (score 0):

From where do you take $xml->products? Aren't you using the Web Service?

Product image is another object like product, and first you should create a new imagen and then adding this image id to product.

Comment: I am retreving data from xml. I have complete image URL like 'http://mysite/myimage.jpg'. Could you please give me a sample of working with image object ?

Answer (score 0):

Use of the `AdminImportControllerCore::copyImg()` function is realy best, though you might not be able to call the function because it is `protected`.

You could make it `public` but thats kinda "dirty" practice. I would much rather see people using this piece of code

```
class MyAdminImportController extends AdminImportControllerCore {
    public static function copyImg($id_entity, $id_image = null, $url = '', $entity = 'products', $regenerate = true) {
        return parent::copyImg($id_entity, $id_image, $url, $entity, $regenerate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can see here as I do. Look at the line 209 which is where the code starts to add the new image.

https://github.com/xabikip/PrestaShopWebService/blob/master/examples/createProduct.php