# Prestashop - How can I add image at the time of product create from code

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have the code through which I am able to create a new prestashop product. I am not able to get some working code that can add image at the time of product create (new product created).

I got few links that shares image upload way but none of it worked. Can someone guide me how can I proceed

[prestashop add images to products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153131/prestashop-add-images-to-products)

[How to add image during programmatic product import in prestashop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447131/how-to-add-image-during-programmatic-product-import-in-prestashop/28451553)

Working Code

```
$product = new Product();        // insert case
// $product = new Product(7467); // update case
$product->name = [$default_lang => $roomname . '/' . $hotelname . ' (Room/Hotel/Ratekey)'];
$product->link_rewrite = [$default_lang => 'hotels'];
$product->price = $price;
$product->description = $ratekey;
$product->id_category = [30];
$product->id_category_default = 30;

// add products
if($product->add()) {
                          $product->updateCategories($product->id_category);
                          StockAvailable::setQuantity((int)$product->id, 0, $product->quantity, Context::getContext()->shop->id);
                        }

// need to write code that adds the image along with the newly product created.
```

When I run the code with new product it's image should also be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix image upload issue. This is for those who might face same issue.

Firstly image upload will work only in controller page and not in core PHP page so call the page on controller.

Suppose in the tpl link you have a button whose on event you will go to  the controller

```
<form id="myform" action="{$link->getModuleLink('hotelapi', 'testing')|escape:'html'}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="testing">
        <input type="submit" name="testsubmit" value="Test Link" />
</form>
```

mymodule/controllers/front/addtocart.php

```
<?php
// class customTestingController extends ModuleFrontController
class hotelapiAddtocartModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    /*public function init()
    {
        echo $_POST['test'];
        echo 'kkkkkkkkkk'; die('dddddddddddd');
    }*/

    public function postProcess()
    {       

        /*===================== Handeling Image for Prestashop Upload: Start ===================== */
             $query = "SELECT `id_product` FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."product` ORDER BY id_product DESC LIMIT 1";
             $id = Db::getInstance()->executeS($query);
             $id_product = $id[0]['id_product'];

             $langId = (int) (Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));


                // checking image
                $image = new Image();
                $image->id = 1;
                $image->position = Image::getHighestPosition($id_product) + 1;
                $image->cover = true; // or false;
                $image->id_product = intval($id_product);

                if(Image::getImagesTotal($id_product)>0)
                 $image->cover = false;
                else
                  $image->cover = true;

                $languages = Language::getLanguages();

                foreach ($languages as $language)
                 $image->legend[$language['id_lang']] = 'Click to view';
                $id_image = $image->id;
                /*if($image->add()) {
                    echo "yes";
                } else {
                    echo "no";
                }*/
                if (($image->validateFields(false, true)) === true &&
                ($image->validateFieldsLang(false, true)) === true && $image->add())
                {   $url = trim($_POST['hotelimage'], "'");    // hotel image
                    // test images
                    // $url = "http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/00/001075/001075a_hb_r_001.jpg";
                    // $url = "http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/original/00/004200/004200a_hb_ro_006.jpg";
                    $image->associateTo($shops);

                    if (!self::copyImg($id_product, $image->id, $url, 'products'))
                    {
                        $image->delete();
                    }

                    echo 'iamge uploaded';
                }
        /*===================== Handeling Image for Prestashop Upload: End ===================== */

        /*===================== Handeling Cart for Product Upload: Start ===================== */
            if ($this->context->cookie->id_cart)
           {
             // die('restrict cart....');
             $cart = new Cart($this->context->cookie->id_cart);


             // To get Product ID
             $query = "SELECT `id_product` FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."product` ORDER BY id_product DESC LIMIT 1";
             $latest_idnumber = Db::getInstance()->executeS($query);

             // getting cart information here
              $customData = $this->context->cookie->id_customer;    //user id
              $quantity   = 1; // room booking qty will always be 1
              $attribute  = 74; //enter the id_product_attribute
              $id_product = (int) $latest_idnumber[0]['id_product'];
              // $id_product = 8067;                                   // product

              $Cart = $this->context->cart;

              /*print_r($Cart->updateQty($quantity, $id_product, $id_product_attribute = null, $id_customization = false, $operator = 'up', $id_address_delivery = 0, $shop = null, $auto_add_cart_rule = true));*/

              $Cart->updateQty($quantity, $id_product, $id_product_attribute = null, $id_customization = false, $operator = 'up', $id_address_delivery = 0, $shop = null, $auto_add_cart_rule = true);

              Tools::redirect('/gb/module/hotelapi/display');


           }

           // create new cart if needed
            if (!isset($cart) OR !$cart->id)
            {
                $cart = new Cart();
                $cart->id_customer = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_customer);
                $cart->id_address_delivery = (int)  (Address::getFirstCustomerAddressId($cart->id_customer));
                $cart->id_address_invoice = $cart->id_address_delivery;
                $cart->id_lang = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_lang);
                $cart->id_currency = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_currency);
                $cart->id_carrier = 1;
                $cart->recyclable = 0;
                $cart->gift = 0;
                $cart->add();
                $this->context->cookie->id_cart = (int)($cart->id);    

                $cart->update();
            }
/*===================== Handeling Cart for Product Upload: End ===================== */

    } // end function

    // This function handels image upload for prestashop product
    function copyImg($id_entity, $id_image = null, $url, $entity = 'products')
            {
                $tmpfile = tempnam(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_, 'ps_import');
                $watermark_types = explode(',', Configuration::get('WATERMARK_TYPES'));

                switch ($entity)
                {
                    default:
                    case 'products':
                        $image_obj = new Image($id_image);
                        $path = $image_obj->getPathForCreation();
                    break;
                    case 'categories':
                        $path = _PS_CAT_IMG_DIR_.(int)$id_entity;
                    break;
                }
                $url = str_replace(' ' , '%20', trim($url));
                // Evaluate the memory required to resize the image: if it's too much, you can't resize it.
                if (!ImageManager::checkImageMemoryLimit($url))
                    return false;
                // 'file_exists' doesn't work on distant file, and getimagesize make the import slower.
                // Just hide the warning, the traitment will be the same.
                if (@copy($url, $tmpfile))
                {
                    ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path.'.jpg');
                    $images_types = ImageType::getImagesTypes($entity);
                    foreach ($images_types as $image_type) 
                    { 
                        ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path.'-'.stripslashes($image_type['name']).'.jpg', $image_type['width'], $image_type['height']); 

                        if (in_array($image_type['id_image_type'], $watermark_types)) 
                            Hook::exec('actionWatermark', array('id_image' => $id_image, 'id_product' => $id_entity)); 
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    unlink($tmpfile);
                    return false;
                }
                unlink($tmpfile);
                return true;
            }
}
```

Cheers !! :)